Issue with GTK boxes/action bars
I have 2 boxes and actionbars. when I add box2 as a child to the window. When I remove the code that adds the box2 to the window, these errors appear when I try to run the compiled app. No errors at compilation but there are errors when I try to run the app.
These are the errors:
(BIDE:12460): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 22:50:34.898: invalid uninstantiatable type '(null)' in cast to 'GtkWidget'

(BIDE:12460): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:50:34.898: gtk_widget_get_parent: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(BIDE:12460): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:50:34.898: gtk_widget_insert_before: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(BIDE:12460): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:50:34.940: gtk_widget_get_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(BIDE:12460): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 22:50:34.940: gtk_widget_child_focus: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is my current code:
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <pango/pango.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//char verString[5] = "0.0.1";
char buffer[100];
//READERS! This code is meant to be easily read for people who want to learn!
GtkWidget *helpWindow;
static void showWindow() {
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow));
//  gtk_widget_set_visible(GTK_WIDGET(windowToOpen), true); 

}

//Handles initializing the window
static void activateWindow(GtkApplication *app) {
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    helpWindow = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    GtkWidget *sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new();
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(sw, TRUE);

    //Info Bar | Bottom
    GtkWidget *infoBar = gtk_action_bar_new();
    GtkWidget *box2 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), box2);
    GtkWidget *sw2 = gtk_scrolled_window_new();
    gtk_widget_set_vexpand(sw2, TRUE);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box2), infoBar);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box2), sw2);



    GtkWidget *verInfo = gtk_label_new("Testing");
    gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(infoBar), GTK_WIDGET(verInfo));
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(verInfo),-1, 200);
    
    

    //Stuff for help window
    GtkWidget *ytURI = gtk_link_button_new_with_label("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvECibTCuY1Txj_DtZTddKQ", "My YouTube");
    GtkWidget *gitURI = gtk_link_button_new_with_label("https://github.com/thatitalianguy08", "My Github");
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow), GTK_WIDGET(ytURI));
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow), GTK_WIDGET(gitURI));
    
    //TopActionBar | Creation
    GtkWidget *topActionBar = gtk_action_bar_new();
    GtkWidget *box = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 5);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIDGET(box));
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), topActionBar);
    gtk_box_append(GTK_BOX(box), sw);

    

        //TopActionBar | TITLE
        GtkWidget *bideLabel = gtk_label_new(NULL);
        gchar *bideLabelText = g_markup_printf_escaped("<b>BIDE</b>");
        gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(bideLabel), bideLabelText);
        gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(topActionBar), GTK_WIDGET(bideLabel));
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(bideLabel), -1, 50);
        //TopActionBar | Open Folder Button
        GtkWidget *openFolder = gtk_button_new();
        gtk_button_set_label(GTK_BUTTON(openFolder), "Open Folder");
        gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(topActionBar), GTK_WIDGET(openFolder));
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(openFolder), -1, 50);

        //TopActionBar | Help Menu Button
        gchar *helpButtonText = g_markup_printf_escaped("<u>HELP</u>");
        GtkWidget *helpButton = gtk_button_new();
        GtkWidget *helpLabel = gtk_label_new("Help");
        gtk_label_set_markup(GTK_LABEL(helpLabel), helpButtonText);
        g_signal_connect_swapped(helpButton, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(showWindow), NULL);  
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(helpButton), -1, 50);
        gtk_button_set_child(GTK_BUTTON(helpButton), GTK_WIDGET(helpLabel));

        //TopActionBar | Save Button
        GtkWidget *saveButton = gtk_button_new_with_label("Save File");
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(GTK_WIDGET(saveButton), -1, 50);
        gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(topActionBar), GTK_WIDGET(saveButton));
        
    
                
        gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(topActionBar), GTK_WIDGET(helpButton));
    gtk_window_set_hide_on_close(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow), true);
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIDGET(box));
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIDGET(box2));
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
    

}

//Main stuff
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkApplication *app = gtk_application_new("me.lufthor.bide", G_APPLICATION_DEFAULT_FLAGS);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(activateWindow), NULL);
    return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

}

I've tried re writing the code for the box2/infoBar.

Welcome to SO. "When I remove the code that adds the box2 to the window, these errors appear" That means, the code you show, does not produce these error messages. That is not very useful. What exactly did you remove from this code? Please show the version that produces these errors. And you should try to run your code in a debugger to see which function call creates these messages.

The problem in this program is that trying to add several children to a GtkWindow.
A GtkWindow can only include ONE child at a time. So if you want to add two GtkBoxes you need three. A GtkBox added to the GtkWindow,and then add the two more to the first GtkBox.
Also children should not be added more than one time.
I first commented out two lines and then received the following result.
  //Stuff for help window
    GtkWidget *ytURI = gtk_link_button_new_with_label("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvECibTCuY1Txj_DtZTddKQ", "My YouTube");
    GtkWidget *gitURI = gtk_link_button_new_with_label("https://github.com/thatitalianguy08", "My Github");
    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow), GTK_WIDGET(ytURI));  // Window set Child
  //  gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow), GTK_WIDGET(gitURI));  // Window set Child

and
  gtk_action_bar_pack_start(GTK_ACTION_BAR(topActionBar), GTK_WIDGET(helpButton));
        gtk_window_set_hide_on_close(GTK_WINDOW(helpWindow), true);
        gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIDGET(box));
        ///gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIDGET(box2));
        gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));




It cannot be ruled out that there are more errors in the program. But this is a principled mistake, without whose correction no further troubleshooting makes sense.
